# XUnit HttpStatusCode does not contain a definition for Should

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am writing XUnit test case. I am getting following error

> Error CS1061  'HttpStatusCode' does not contain a definition for 'Should' and no accessible extension method 'Should' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpStatusCode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What does the error say and how to solve it. Please any one try to help me.

Thank you..

Comment: Share us the code what you used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `Should`, there is no built-in `Should` to achieve the similiar function `Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, defaultPage.StatusCode);`.

You could try [shouldly](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly) to simplify the `Assert.Equal`.

- Install-Package Shouldly
- Referer by `using Shouldly;`
- Useage

  ```
      public async Task Test()
  {
      var server = new TestServer(WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
          .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
          );
      var response = await server.CreateClient().GetAsync(@"/test");
      response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);

      var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the help